# Application compatible with iPhone 3G and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode

AFAIK, in Xcode 4.5, `armv6` support has been deprecated and the deployment target should be minimum `iOS 4.3`.

Therefore, **it is not possible to develop an application which works on iPhone 3G and iPhone 5**. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Well, you could build your app with older Xcode so it will work on both iPhone 3G and iPhone 5, but not use up entire screen on the iPhone 5. This was intended, iPhone 3G support is long gone.

Edit: there is an unofficial solution provided as an answer here: [How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12619124/877465)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has stopped accepting builds that support pre iOS5 devices and contain an iPhone 5 launch image. Here is the email for the last build I submitted that was build on Xcode 4.4.1

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team