# Can I support iOS from version 3.0 to 6.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-5

I updated my app code to support iOS 6 (of course I installed xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 SDK).

My deployment target is still 3.0
I made an archive but it didn't validate and complained about MISSING architecture armv6 but I my warnings I can see :

```
warning: architecture armv6 is not supported (current ARCHS = "armv7 armv7s armv6").
warning: iOS deployment targets lower than 4.3 are not supported (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7 armv7s armv6").
```

So what? Am I forced to drop armv6 and all devices that run iOS < 4.3 ?
Isn't there a way to support iOS from version 3.0 to 6.0 ?

Comment: Not really sure why you would want to?  Is there any particular reason?  The %age of devices using iOS3 is now very small.

Comment: yes indeed but my app was supporting ios 3.0 until now then I'd like to keep the support of ios 3.0 and to add support for ios 6 as well

Comment: Your app will continue to work on iOS3 exactly as it is.  They can still use it they just won't be able to update it.  TBH, I really only write apps now targeted at 5.0 or higher and my next update will be for 6.0.  I don't know the actual answer to your question but I wouldn't check either.  Just drop support for iOS3.

Comment: Probably you have to think about give up your iOS3 support. Just look at the statistics. For a lot of apps after the iOS6 release the amount of users with iOS6 within one week was over 60%!

Comment: Are iOS 6 users having trouble running you app?

Comment: What is the situation when updating apps, e.g. an old app created using iOS 3.0 compiled for armv6, and adding a new binary compiled in 6.0 for armv7, will Apple allow that? I'm pretty sure we won't be able to add the update due to required device capabilities?

Comment: yes Apple will allow it. Your app won't just be available in all iOS < version 6 anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 does not support generating ARM6 code. You will indeed have to drop support for those devices for new releases of your App when built using Xcode 4.5.

From the [Xcode 4.5 Release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html):

> This version of Xcode does not generate armv6 binaries. 12282156

Still I need to emphasize that iOS3 still is supported for old projects. When building new projects, the lowest offered iOS deployment target is 4.3. But then again, that is almost an academic piece of information since only the iPhone 3GS runs on the ARM7 platform and orignally was released with iOS3, back in 2009 (2G and 3G are ARM6 platform devices). That 3GS got very recently discontinued (12th September 2012) but does support the complete update path of iOS (up until and including iOS6 - whereas some iOS6 features are missing on that device).

Comment: @borrrden true for new projects, untrue for old projects. Will edit my answer accordingly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a copy of XCode 4.3 to build your iOS 3 apps thats the only way.

Kinda Sucks I would think you should be able to target lower versions of the OS but I do understand the the why Apple thinks is just to stop supporting things after a time, which in the big picture is why i like iOS over Droid!

Answer (score 0):

even Xcode 5 can genereate binaries with armv6 support after light modify it.
Look this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836808/751932