# App with deployment target of 4.0 won't install on "too old" 4.0.1 device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app where the deployment target is set at iOS 4.0, yet trying to run it on a 4.0.1 device results in this:

"The version of iOS on XXX is too old for use with this version of the iOS SKD"

As the installed OS version of 4.0.1 is > than the deployment target why does it say the OS is too old.

(The app will sucesfully install/run on other devices that has 4.3, 5.n, 6.n installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5 *(with support for the iPhone 5 / armv7s)*, you can only support iOS 4.3 as the lowest possible deployment target.

Comment: You can do it with some hacks with Xcode 4.5.2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12836808#12836808