# How do you build / distribute for < iOS 4.3 given Xcode no longer supports armv6?

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5)

I have a requirement to support iOS 4.0 onwards.

However Xcode no longer supports armv6, therefore is it possible to build and distribute a single application that will support 4, 5, and 6?

Its my understanding if I was to build using an older version of Xcode then it wouldn't be able to support the 4" iPhone 5 screen size.

Therefore it seems its now impossible to create one single app that could support 4.0 upwards. Is this correct and it would be necessary to create one app for 4.3 onwards and one for < 4.3?

If that's the case, then does that mean 2 separate app submissions? And would they have to be named differently in the app store or could they have the same name etc.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation but need to support 3.2+. However, I haven't even started to look into yet.

Comment: The above-linked question has a couple of different ways of integrating ARMv6 and older iOS version support into a single binary that also supports iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple wants you to move up so they are forcing you to make this decision. I don't think its a good idea to make two builds. The problem with that is the older build can be used for all devices but the newer will only work on modern devices (which is the vast majority anyway).

I think you should consider this plan.

1. If you app is already in the store update it as much as you can while continuing support for < iOS 4.3 and give people time to move up to it. If its a new app then submit that and do the same.
2. Update it to the newest SDK and submit an update eventually that is > iOS 4.3.

This will let you give everyone a chance but eventually you'll only have one build in the store (having two will be confusing for people and decrease your rank because it will be shared).

I think this could be a good strategy unless you have millions of users and you know that a very large portion of your active uses are on very old hardware that can't upgrade.

Comment: Highly unlikely to be much of a market on less < 5.x anymore. Our traffic a few months ago was <10% pre 5.0 even with a 4.3 supported app. We upgraded our app to 5.X and had no complaints. Unless you have ancient hardware that can't upgrade everyone upgrades iOS almost instantly. We got to 80% 6.X on that same iPhone app within 1 week after 6.0 came out.

Comment: Same with me but some people have a situation where they have to give some support for those devices. I ditched supporting them a while ago.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer... Apple says to "move on", so you've just gotta move on... also see http://tewha.net/2012/06/dont-write-new-apps-that-target-ios-4/ (and this is even outdated, so the stats are even more convincing now to drop anything less than 5.0)