# Universal app's crash reports don't work with symbolicatecrash

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

The following [solution by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5) is a great method for creating a universal app, with ARMV6, ARMV7, & ARMV7s.

However the crash reports do not work with symbolicatecrash regardless of whether I use the dSYM from Release_armv6-iphoneos or release-iphoneos. I have tried symbolicatecrash from 4.5 and 4.3. Has anyone found a way to get this to work?