# How to target both iOS 4.2.1 and iOS 6.1 with 4" retina display without letterboxing

Tags: ios, retina-display

As Xcode 4.4 does not support iOS 6.1 devices with 4" retina display and Xcode 4.6 does not support ios 4.2 devices I submitted two different applications to the App Store, one compiled with 4.4 and one with 4.6 so I can target iOS devices from 3G and upwards without having to have letterboxed view in iPhone 5 and latest iPod Touch. The Quality Assurance has rejected the application as duplicate. How is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5)

Comment: I have read that question and while it adds armv6 in Xcode 4.5 it doesn't provide a way to support non-letterboxed iPhone 5 application